# Woocommerce checkout : create custom fee if products are from different categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

### SCENARIO :

We are an online multi-restaurant delivery service :

And we need to add an extra fee if the customer orders from 2 or more different restaurants. So for each restaurant we add an extra 2€ fee.

EXAMPLES :

- customer selects 1 meal : no fee
- customer selects 2 meals from same restaurant : no fee
- customer selects 2 meals from 2 diff restaurants : 2€ extra fee
- customer selects 3 meals from 3 diff restaurants : 2€ + 2€ = 4€
- customer selects 4 meals from 4 diff restaurants : 2€ + 2€ +2€ = 6€
  ... and so on

CATEGORIES :

- Each restaurant is 1 category
- Each meal has more than 1 category AND
- We need to check if this category in particular is equal or different for each meal on cart checkout

### PROBLEM :

Here's what we think might work :

- We might have to scroll thru each meal (product) on cart checkout AND
- We have to get the categories for each meal AND
- Compare each meal + check if they belong to diff restaurants

Restaurants are a sub-category like :

City (top cat.) -> Restaurant (child cat.) -> Meal (product)

### SOLUTION :

So we think might be easy to write some code that checks if products (meals) on cart checkout are from more than 1 category (restaurant) ? And then apply the additional fee ?

Need some help here on how to best approach this scenario. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To do so, add follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php -

```
function woo_add_cart_fee() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    $restaurant = array();
    foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
        $available_restaurant_cat_ids = array(); // Replace the empty array with all avaiable 'restaurants' categories ids
        $restaurant_list_ids = wp_get_post_terms($values['data']->get_id(),'product_cat',array('fields'=>'ids')); // we assumed that restaurant belongs to product_cat
        if($restaurant_list_ids){
            foreach ($restaurant_list_ids as $id) {
                if(!in_array($id, $available_restaurant_cat_ids)) continue; // id not belongs to restaurant
                if(!in_array($id, $restaurant)){
                    $restaurant[] = $id;
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    $restaurant_multiply = count($restaurant) - 1; // first restaurant id free
    $extra_fee = 2; // 2 euro

    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __('Extra fees', 'woocommerce'), $extra_fee*$restaurant_multiply );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' );
```

Comment: Thank you itzmekhokan, we're almost there!

I've updated the description with more information, please take a look.

Because each meal (product) can be associated with multiple categories, we might need to compare a specific category between all the meals - and then check if they are different.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Yes, its possible. First of all you have to pick all available restaurants (categoires) ids. After then you have to add extra checking on above code like if product categories ids present in your all picked restaurants ids, then only insert into restaurant array.

Comment: Can you update the code you wrote to reflect this? That would be great! Thank you so much for your contribution.

Comment: @Aguarella, I updated the code, but make sure that you have all the available restaurants categories ids in $available_restaurant_cat_ids variable.

Comment: Thank you itzmekhokan! Give us a moment while we figure this one out and adapt - I will let you know the results. Your work and prompt feedback is much appreciated by us all.